# Guided Back-propagation in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, backpropagation

I would like to implement in TensorFlow the technique of "Guided back-propagation" introduced in this  [Paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6806.pdf)  and which is described in this  [recipe](https://github.com/Lasagne/Recipes/blob/master/examples/Saliency%20Maps%20and%20Guided%20Backpropagation.ipynb) .

Computationally that means that when I compute the gradient e.g., of the input wrt. the output of the NN, I will have to **modify the gradients computed at every RELU unit**. Concretely, the back-propagated signal on those units must be thresholded on zero, to make this technique work. In other words the partial derivative of the RELUs that are negative must be ignored.

Given that I am interested in applying these gradient computations only on *test examples*, i.e., I don't want to update the model's parameters - how shall I do it?

I tried (unsuccessfully) two things so far:

1. Use **tf.py_func** to wrap my simple numpy version of a RELU, which then is eligible to redefine it's gradient operation via the **g.gradient_override_map** context manager.
2. Gather the forward/backward values of BackProp and apply the thresholding on those stemming from Relus.

I failed with both approaches because they require some knowledge of the internals of TF that currently I don't have.

Can anyone suggest any other route, or sketch the code?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

The better solution (your approach 1) with [`ops.RegisterGradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#RegisterGradient) and `tf.Graph.gradient_override_map`. Together they override the gradient computation for a pre-defined Op, e.g. Relu within the `gradient_override_map` context using only python code.

```
@ops.RegisterGradient("GuidedRelu")
def _GuidedReluGrad(op, grad):
    return tf.where(0. < grad, gen_nn_ops._relu_grad(grad, op.outputs[0]), tf.zeros(grad.get_shape()))

...
with g.gradient_override_map({'Relu': 'GuidedRelu'}):
    y = tf.nn.relu(x)
```

here is the full example implementation of guided relu: https://gist.github.com/falcondai/561d5eec7fed9ebf48751d124a77b087

**Update**: in Tensorflow >= 1.0, `tf.select` is renamed to `tf.where`. I updated the snippet accordingly. (Thanks @sbond for bringing this to my attention :)

Comment: beware that you need to wrap the graph construction involving the relu op *inside* the `gradient_override_map` context.

Comment: Thank you, @Falcon, this works well. I also had to replace tf.select by tf.where, as I am using TF version 1.2.

Comment: @sbond Thanks for the update. I edited my post to include your comment.

Answer (score 6):

The `tf.gradients` has the `grad_ys` parameter that can be used for this purpose. Suppose your network has just one `relu` layer as follows :

```
before_relu = f1(inputs, params)
after_relu = tf.nn.relu(before_relu)
loss = f2(after_relu, params, targets)
```

First, compute the derivative up to `after_relu`.

```
Dafter_relu = tf.gradients(loss, after_relu)[0]
```

Then threshold your gradients that you send down.

```
Dafter_relu_thresholded = tf.select(Dafter_relu < 0.0, 0.0, Dafter_relu)
```

Compute the actual gradients w.r.t to `params`.

```
Dparams = tf.gradients(after_relu, params, grad_ys=Dafter_relu_thresholded)
```

You can easily extend this same method for a network with many `relu` layers.

Comment: Hi Kaveman, thanks a lot for the prompt reply. In your last tf.gradients call you are intentionally passing the Dafter_relu as the first argument?

Comment: Also, I am still confused wrt. how to generalize this on a network with many layers in an way that works for any NN that has RELU elements.  For this part wouldn't you need to trace all the input/output of each RELU element and 'chain' your previously described logic? Thanks.

Comment: @Peter, sorry, that was a typo. The second call to `tf.gradients` is `after_relu` w.r.t. `params`.

Comment: Yes, to generalize, you have to identify all the relu layers, and run the above logic on each of the layers.

Comment: @keveman Could you please elaborate on what do functions f1 and f2 compute essentially how do I calculate the loss?For example Loss at the final layer is cross entropy then what would be loss in any intermediate CNN layer.